# Functional way to reverse cumulative sum?

Tags: r

If I have a vector of a cumulative sum, e.g.

```
> vec <- cumsum(1:10)
[1]  1  3  6 10 15 21 28 36 45 55
```

is there a functional way to translate `vec` into it's original vector of `c(1:10)`?

Right now, I'm using  a for-loop that goes:

```
> result <- vec[1]
> for (i in 2:length(vec)) result <- append(result, vec[i]-vec[i-1])
> result
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

But that doesn't seem very R like to me... Any ideas?

Comment: I guess your loop could be "vectorised" like `c(vec[1], vec[-1] - vec[-length(vec)])`

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Just use `diff` to get the successive differences:

```
> c(vec[1],diff(vec))
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Comment: Faster fingers than I!

Comment: @Justin So fast that I finished typing this comment before I started!

Comment: This solution can be problematic for `mutate(new = diff(old))` as the length out of `diff()` is n-1.

Comment: @AndrewMcCartney Did you notice that my answer included appending a value to the front specifically to make the lengths match?

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else is looking to reverse a `cumsum` accross an entire `dataframe`, I used the following :

My dataframe is `Factor.df`, the first column is a series of `character` - hence the selection from the second column. Hope it helps

```
Factor.df[,2:ncol(Factor.df)] <- Factor.df[,2:ncol(Factor.df)] %>% dplyr::mutate_each(dplyr::funs((.) - dplyr::lag(.)))
```